# How do I access the resources directory for a calling program in Java

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I have a library which is used by a program. This library loads a special directory in the resources folder.

in the library I have the method

```
public class DataRegistry{

    public static File getSpecialDirectory(){
        String resourceName = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("data").getFile().replace("%20", " ");
        File file = new File(resourceName);
        return file;
    }

}
```

in my program I have the main method

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    System.out.println(Data.getSpecialDirectory());
}
```

When I execute the getSpecialDirectory() in a junit test within the data program, the resource is fetched and all is well.

When I execute the getSpecialDirectory() in the main method outside the data program (imported jar) I get the jars data directory and not the directory the program executing the thread is expecting.

I figured getting the parent class loader would have solved this issue... I believe I may have a fundamental issue in my understanding here.

For clarity:

(library)
Line 15 of this file: https://gist.github.com/AnthonyClink/11275442

(Usage)
Line 31 of this file: 
https://gist.github.com/AnthonyClink/11275661

My poms may have something to do with it, so sharing them is probably important:\

(Library)
https://github.com/Clinkworks/Neptical/blob/master/pom.xml

(Usage)
https://github.com/Clinkworks/Neptical-Maven-Plugin/blob/master/pom.xml

Comment: What are you trying to acheive? Get path to a folder relative to your DataMojo class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do you want the directory where the Java program was loaded from ? Can try

   File f = new File(".").getCanconicalFile();
2. Or if you want all the places could try parsing the classpath from System.env or use the default class loader
3. If you want a directory relative to the jar from where your classes were loaded: Quoting from http://www.nakov.com/blog/2008/06/11/finding-the-directory-where-your-java-class-file-is-loaded-from/

   URL classesRootDir = getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();

> The above returns the base directory used when loading your .class
>   files. It does not contain the package. It contains the classpath
>   directory only. For example, in a console application the above
>   returns someting like this:
>
> file:/C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/Administrator/workspace/TestPrj/bin/
>
> In a Web application it returns someting like this:
>
> file:/C:/Tomcat/webapps/MyApp/WEB-INF/classes/

FYI This might apply if the user id running program cannot read all folders: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getProtectionDomain%28%29

1. or pass a .class object of the calling class as a parameter and get its classloader

Comment: You should never ever use java.io.File objects to read the content of jar resources or web resources. This relies on the application server exploding your WAR file upon deployment - and many of them don't do that at all. The servlet and JDK API's provide other mechanisms for doing that.

Comment: How is this doing that? "getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()" could be a war? guess need to check if file object is a file or a dir and else take parent?

Comment: wasn't aware of the new File(".") that was pretty slick thank you.

Answer (score 5):

1. Maven uses the target/classes and target/test-classes directories to compose the classpath used to run unit tests. The content of your src/main/resources and src/test/resources gets copied to these locations together with the compiled java sources (the .class files).
2. [java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) returns a [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html).
3. In the unit test situation, ClassLoader.getResource returns a file:// schemed URL, and your code works as expected.
4. When your code is executed when packaged in a jar file, ClassLoader.getResource no longer returns a file:// schemed URL. It can't because the resource is no longer a separate entity in a file system - it's buried inside the jar file. What you actually get is a jar:file:// schemed URL.
5. jar: URLs cannot be accessed through a [java.io.File] object.

If you only need to read the content of the resource you should use [java.lang.ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(...)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) and read the content from that.

Note that it is not possible to update the content of class loader resources.

Comment: i think he wants the parent folder and then grab some other resources that are relative to that folder - in a sub directory called data

Comment: Right, this is read only... however my issue is not knowing how to read the stream, but how to get the url of the file. I am using maven, and by convention I expect the user of the library to be using maven. Maven does compile those resources, and I do not want to url to the jar file, I want the url of the users application class root. Since the library is in a jar, I cannot seem to target the correct directory. If you can assist me in targeting that directory I will be very happy to accept this detailed answer.

Comment: There is no file. There is no file system. Instead of passing a java.io.File object around, pass the URL that you get from j.l.ClassLoader.getResource(...)

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that you have a directory for your resources as far as I know. Java provide methods to get a resource as a [InputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29), but nothing that can easily get the File for a resource, although it is possible to [get the URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) for a given resource.

If you need a special working directory in your application, I recommend having that passed as a system property, a program parameter, a web application parameter, or something else that lets you know where your application files are. You can even populate this directory with a ZIP file that you include as a resource in your application, as the ZIP libraries in Java do accept input streams as parameters.

Answer (score 0):

While user @tgkprog is right and his answer correct, I can hardly imagine that you really want what you seem to have asked for and what he correctly answered in (3). Please edit your question and explain

- what the output should look like if `resourceName` would be printed to the console,
- if you really want the JAR file's location (in my test case that would be something like *file:/C:/Users/Alexander/.m2/repository/com/clinkworks/neptical/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/data*, which does not make sense because you do not want to read from or even write to the local Maven cache),
- or if you maybe rather want to read a resource directly from the JAR file or any other location such as the current working directory etc.

Otherwise I am afraid there is no good way to answer the question.

Comment: I think it would be in the local maven cache if your running from within an IDE ... in a deployed app can be any directory as long you have added that path to classpath

Comment: Well, a stable solution should work in all environments and not assume a specific runtime deployment scenario - at least not one the original poster has not even described. Thus my inquiry for more detailed explanation.